# Copying IAM config between projects on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm using the project per environment method to manage my staging and production environment on GCP, but I'm not sure how I can make sure the two environments have the same configurations.

For example, can I export the IAM config from one project and import it into another project? Or is there a way that I can make sure that the configuration of the two projects is close enough?

Thanks.

Comment: [https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/copy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/copy)

This gcloud command allows you to copy IAM permissions from one project to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use “get-iam-policy” and “set-iam-policy” in your projects to perfectly duplicate the policies from one project onto another (the command is singular but it copies all parts of the policy you do not need to iterate through the roles or anything of the sort).

Here are the links that you can refer more information on the gcloud commands mentioned

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/set-iam-policy